# Postgres many to one relationship join multiple tables and select all rows, provided that at least one row matches some criterea

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a schema something like

```sql
create table if not exists user (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table if not exists post (
  id serial primary key,
  user_id integer not null references user (id),
  score integer not null
)
```

I want to run a query that selects a row from the user table by ID, and all the rows that reference it from the post table, provided that at least one row in the post table has a score of greater than some number *n* (e.g. 50). I'm not exactly sure how to do this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions.  Let me assume that `post` has a `user_id` column so the tables can be tied together:

```
select u.*
from user u join
     (select p.*, max(score) over (partition by user_id) as max_score
      from post p
     ) p
     on p.user_id = u.id
where p.max_score > 50;
```

If you just wanted all scores, then aggregation with filtering might be sufficient:

```
select u.*, array_agg(p.score order by p.score desc)
from user u join
     post p
     ) p
     on p.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
having max(p.score) > 50;
```